# function still running after .hide()?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors, popup, modal-dialog

I have a link whenever I click, there's a popup. I've set up a modal window within a function and it does some other stuff within it. In the modal window, I have a close button. But for some reason

```
function popup(){
//dostuff
}


$('selector').hover(function(){
   $('open_selector').click(function(){
   popup();
});
},function(){
   //button to .hide();
});
```

When I hid the popup, the stuff in the function still operates. Shouldn't it not do anything? unless I click on the link again?

Thanks!

Edit: I have an element that is hidden and I wanted to show it on hover, thats why I have the hover statement. But I forgot to add a button close in this script which closes the popup();

```
$('button_selector').click(function(){
//hide the dialog box that pops up (in this case popup())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
$('selector').hover(function(){
   $('open_selector').click(function(){
       popup();
    });  
},function(){
   //button to .hide();
});
```

First, you're subscribing an event inside of a hover function.  Why not put this in your document.ready handler

```
$('open_selector').click(function(){
   popup();
});
```

The way you have it, the click handler would not be active until you first hovered over this element.  Also, this selector will try to find **tags** named 'open_selector' - is this a class?  If so, you want `$('.open_selector').click(` - ditto for `$('selector').hover`

---

As far as your original question, the second function, what you list as

```
,function(){
   //button to .hide();
}
```

is what is supposed to execute whenever the mouse hovers **out**.  It will always execute when your mouse hovers out of whatever your original selector was.

Comment: Hi I have edited my post, I forgot to mention about a close button that closes the popup();